# Using Flickr API to get images information

Tags: python, flickr

I want to give a **keyword** as input and find information of images in terms of **likes, favourites, comments, description** etc.

Version 3 is out here.

I have read of functions which provide information corresponding to a user_id or photo_id. But, what about keywords ?

Is there anything like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at flickr's [search](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) and [photos.getInfo](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) APIs.